# Prove that de-bruijn graph has Hamiltonian cycle?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

**Let $G_{2,n}$ be a de-bruijn graph.**

We remove the vertex `11...11` and the vertex `00...00` and **all** edges connected to them.

**Q: For which range of values for n (n>2) the new graph has Hamiltonian cycle?**

How may I solve this?
Her's an image of **all** the affected vertices in the new graph.

Her's an image:
[image]

Comment: Have you learned about reflected Gray codes?

Comment: @saulspatz Never heard of this sorry (thus can't use it)

Comment: You can't just refer to it in your homework, but if you search on the web for it, you'll see it's just what you need.  It shows you haw to make a Hamilton cycle on $G_{2,n}$ from a Hamilton cycle on  $G_{2,n-1}$ The same trick works when the two vertices are deleted.  So you just need to find the smallest $n$ for which a Hamilton cycle exists, and use the reflection trick o get Hamiltons cycles for all larger $n$.

Comment: Ok I read about it but yet wasn't successful in doing it on this specific question